# Angular - Access DOM Element From Just Loaded Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I just started Angular last week and I am struggling to access DOM from a template thats just loaded. Here's whats happening -

***index.html***

```
<div class="template" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-include="template_url"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Load Top" ng-click="loadTopTemplate()">
</div>
```

*templates*/***top.html***

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, myObjectItem) in myObject">
    <span id="{{key}}">{{myObjectItem | uppercase}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<span id="staticElement">Static Element</span>
```

***app.js***

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myObject = {"item1": "one", "item2": "two", "item3": "three", "item4": "four", "item5": "five"};
  $scope.loadTopTemplate = function() {
    $scope.template_url = 'top.html';
  }

  $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
    console.debug("template loaded");
    console.debug("Static element text: " + document.getElementById("staticElement").innerHTML); //works
    console.debug("Dynamic element text: " + document.getElementById("item5").innerHTML); //doesn't work
  });
});
```

I am not able to access dynamic elements from ***top.html*** which gets loaded in DOM later on using `ng-repeat`. Please let me know how to resolve this. Thanks!

> Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/rRRRkJ20bm00yqslMtnS?p=preview

Comment: Is that an actual copy of your code? If yes, you are missing a closing bracket the the end of your event-listener. $scope.$on('...', function() {...}); Apart from that, your code-snipped works for me without a flaw.

Comment: The same for me. I think it's best if you, skos, could create a fiddle where you replicate the issue.

Comment: @PerfectPixel No thats not my actual code. I am able to load template and print this `console.debug("template loaded")`

Comment: I'm using basically the same mechanism in different projects. Switching ng-includes on click. The only difference is that I use a service to provide the URL to the loaded partials and some convenience functions. However, I have not yet encountered an issue with DOM access...

Comment: @PerfectPixel You're right. it works that way. I should have had put the actual code to explain the issue. Have edited my question and added [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rRRRkJ20bm00yqslMtnS?p=preview). Please let me know if you could help. Thanks!

Comment: I see the issue and used $timeout as suggested earlier and it works. The event is fired, the template is included, but the ng-repeat is not yet evaluated. Therefore, the static element is accessible but not the dynamic ones. $timeout lets angular finish the evaluation as it interrupts the javascript execution and let angular step in with a digest-cycle. I modified your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TCTPZcAd2Lnrd6c4dMyx?p=preview

Comment: there is onload event IIRC

Comment: @PerfectPixel Seems like it did the trick. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this issue occurs when the event is fired before the DOM is updated.

A common solution is to wrap your access to the DOM in a $timeout:

```
$timeout(function() {
    console.debug($("#myDiv"));
});
```

$timeout without a delay will let angular finish the digest-cycle and update the DOM before trying to access it.

**Edit:**
Here is your modified plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/TCTPZcAd2Lnrd6c4dMyx?p=preview

Comment: It's an awful answer, you shouldn't be relying on timeouts to load anything!

Comment: Loading and rendering are two different pair of shoes. And the need to use timeouts sometimes are widely discussed on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have written `$scope.template_url = 'templates/top.html'` in function, which gets call on `ng-click` so that means your page is available when your click event is done.
So you have to declare top.html outside the function.

```
$scope.template_url = 'templates/top.html';

<div class="template">
   <div ng-include="template_url"></div>
</div>
```

**OR** if you want to add in function then call function first then call the `$scope` object.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try doing a scope.$apply after you have called the loadTopTemplate function?

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: If you read your link, you will realise that scope.$apply is used manually if you CHANGE anything outside an angular context. In this case, there is no change outside a context.